# Laravel/Livewire differentiate two dropdown menus in of the same model

Tags: laravel

Context: I have a category with subcategories; these categories load using a foreach in my Blade file. These subcategories have a dropdown to select data from them. My problem is that when I change the dropdown of one of the subcategories, the other subcategories change too.

```
@foreach ($subcategories as subcategory )

<x-simple-select wire:model="subcategory_id" :wire:key="$subcategory->id"
    name="subcategory" id="{{$subcategory->id}}"
    :options='$types' value-field='subcategory' text-field='subcategory'
/>

@endforeach
```

I want to save the selected data from the dropdown using updatedSubcategoryId($value), but I don't know how to save it since all the subcategories are changed and not just one.

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured out to do.the all idea was wrong (i'm new in livewire).
In case it serves to someone:

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="save()">

  @foreach ($subcategories as $key => $subcategory )

    <x-simple-select wire:model.defer="subcategories.{{$key}}.id" :options='$types' />

  @endforeach

  <button type="submit">save</button>

</form>
```

and then in the controller:

```html
protected $rules = [
  'subcategories.*.id' => '',
  ];

public function save()
{
  $this->validate();
  foreach ($this->subcategories as $subcategory) {
  $subcategory->save();
}
```